# Why sphere geometry take more time to render than cube geometry while both of them have equal faces value?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created a cube from BoxGeometry and created a sphere from SphereGeometry.
(those objects spin around itself)
When a number of both objects were increased, i found that sphere take more time to render than cube. 
For example

500 cubes get 60 FPS

500 spheres get 45 FPS

while each object has the same 12 faces.

Why is it?

```
for(var i = 0; i <amount ; i++){
    posX = posX + size;

    if(i%20 == 0){
        posX = -105;
        posZ = posZ + size;
    }

    if(i%500 == 0){
        posX = -105;
        posZ = -500;
        posY = posY + size;
    } // To fit for view, five hundred objects were stacked per level. 

        sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments);
        sphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x219621, specular: 0xFFE7BA, shininess: 5, opacity: 1, transparent: true});
        sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMat);
        sphereMesh.rotation.x =0;
        sphereMesh.rotation.y =0;
        sphereMesh.rotation.z =0;
        sphereMesh.position.x = posX;
        sphereMesh.position.y = posY;
        sphereMesh.position.z = posZ;
        sphereMesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
        sphereMesh.updateMatrix();
        sphereMesh.address = i;
        countID = i;

        objectsID[countID] = sphereMesh;
        addList[sphereMesh.address] = objectsID[countID];
        scene.add(objectsID[countID]);
    }

function render()
{
    var add_len = addList.length;
    for(var i=0; i< add_len; i++ )
        {
            addList[i].rotation.y += 1;
            addList[i].matrixAutoUpdate = false;
            addList[i].updateMatrix();
        }
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( render ); 
}
```

these are pictures for

500 spheres

[image: 500 Spheres]

500 cubes

[image: 500 Cubes]

i set radius = 25, WidthSegments = 3 and heightSegments = 2 
. So it has 12 faces but the output unlike the spherical shape
(3 and 2 are a minimum value which define in three.js Docs for segment)

For cubes creating, i use the same method and each cube has 12 faces.
Both testing case are run on the same environment.

i wonder why they have a difference performance.
maybe cause from a structure inside BoxGeometry and SphereGeometry?

Comment: Without code, we can only guess.

Comment: How do you make a sphere with 12 faces?

Answer (score -1):

Are the faces for both objects always pointing in the same direction (e.g. did you create a '12 face cube' out of a sphere somehow)?

If not, then normals and lighting would be more varied on the non-cubed object since the cube would have more faces that could share the same data (less calculations).

Comment: Please comment regarding the reason to down vote?  I thought it was a reasonable suggestion that when the two triangles of each cube face are on the same plane, then you (or the API) would only need to calculate the normal once instead of twice for the purposes of lighting/shading.  For a spherical object (even with only 12 faces) it's more likely that every face will be on a different plane, and so you'd have to have 12 normals calculated (twice as many)?  Thank you.